# Bootstrap Tapdrop jQuery in angular.js controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I saw Bootstrap Tapdrop library and it is perfect for dropdown in my responsive tabs. My app works with angular.js, but add the bootstrap-tapdrop.js in my index.html .

I want to call:

```
$('.nav-tabs').tabdrop({align:'left'});
```

into my angularjs app but nothing works. However, when I call this from chrome console works ok.

How can I add this sentence jQuery angular.js my driver? is there anyway? or..how can I use this library from angular.js? I have sought similar things in angular but can not find.

Thanks

Comment: you can create a demo app on plnkr then we can help troubleshoot. From current info we have, we don't even know whether bootstrap tapdrop is loaded when this sentence is executed.

Comment: You can try the jQuery Passthrough from here: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a directive in order to use jQuery plugins or whenever you want to attach client side behavior to elements using jQuery or any third party plugins.

Try something like this.

```
angular.module('main')
  .directive('my-tabs-directive', [ function ($timeout, $sce) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          //Write any plugin logic here
          element.tabdrop({align: 'left'});
        },
        templateUrl: 'passYourTemplateUrl'//You can also use inline template
      };
    }
  ]);
```

You can understand more about angularJs directive here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Thanks!! I try with this but not works. I made the directive and call it with <div my-tabs-directive></div> but the apps no toggle or something. I changed element.tabdrop({align: 'left'}); with element(".nav-tabs").tabdrop({align: 'left'}); with same results. ;(

Comment: The example I gave is for tag `my-tabs-directive`. You cannot use it as an attribute. For using it as an attribute you to change `restrict` to `A`. And use jQuery `find` method to find the element.